# Automatically insert characters with Ultisnips upon exiting Insert mode

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

In Ultisnips, is there a way to create a snippet that will replace empty space in the snippet with a `*` character upon exiting Insert mode (or as I type)?

For example, I have a snippet that looks like so:

```
snippet cch
/******************************/
/* ${1} */
/******************************/
endsnippet
```

After expanding this snippet, I would like to fill the space around the input `${1}` with `*` characters after exiting Insert mode such that the width of this line will match the lines above and below.

So if I type `cch <tab>` and then `Function Prototypes <Esc>` it will look like the following:

```
/******************************/
/***** Function Prototypes ****/
/******************************/
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know how exactly it should be but I have a guess. You should use python interpolation on ultisnips and inside it len("your string"). here a screencast about python interpolation in ultisnps: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/ultisnips-python-interpolation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I have found in `plugged/vim-snippets/UltiSnips/all.snippets` a snippet called `box` that makes something like that:

```
----------------------
-  some text inside  -
----------------------
```

After reading a little bit more the code I figured out that if you set your filetype like `:setf c` and type `box<tab>`you will get your something like:

```
/*************
*  my text  *
*************/
```

This means you just have to make a slightly different version of `all.snippets`